# What is C# analog of C fread()?

Tags: c#, c, fread

What is C#   analog of C fread()?

In [C code here we use](http://cekirdek.pardus.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/api-example_8c-source.html)

```
fread(inbuf, 1, AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE, f);
```

What could be its exact analog?

Comment: Binary formatter - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx ?

Comment: Try the `LagThenLagSomeMore` function. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest would be [`Stream.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx)

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Stream.Read(...)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx